# Custom directive not working on Android 4.4.2 but works on Android 6.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive

I have a cordova app which uses angularjs. There is a custom directive to change the content of ng-model in the view.

The custom directive is a follows:

```
MyApp.directive('editModel', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        require: 'ngModel',
        compile: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {  
            return function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                var name = scope.content.MyTest.MyName;
                if (name.includes(' ')) {
                    var ary = name.split(' ');
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ary[0]);
                } else {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(name);
                }
                ngModel.$render();
            };
        }

    };
});
```

This directive is used as follows:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" id="input_model" edit-Model ng-model="content.MyTest.MyName"  />
```

The directive does its job when the app runs on an android 6.0 device or an iOS device. But fails when the app runs on android 4.4.2.

Unable to figure out what's causing it to not work on android 4.4.2 and how to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly goes wrong? Is the input even displayed? Any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The input is displayed but the directive has no effect on the input. 
For example, if my input text is 'Test Me'. According to the directive, the ngModel should now show only 'Test'. This is precisely how it works in iOS and Android 6. But in Android 4.4.2, it shows as 'Test Me' still.